# Can I get the number of Facebook Likes a page that is not on my domain received?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

Is it possible to get the number of Facebook Likes made on any url, even if I don't own that url's domain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graph API how get facebook page members/likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632000/graph-api-how-get-facebook-page-members-likes)

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you can query specific URLs:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27https://stackoverflow.com/%27&format=json

Comment: It seems to be largely under reporting various websites that I have tested against. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: With Facebook's penchant for continually switching things up, I'd be wary of a three year old answer--even if it is mine.  Have you tried looking at what the Graph API is returning for your sites?

Comment: The count that a like button shows isn't just the value of like_count, but the sum of share_count, like_count and comment_count, which can be read from total_count. There's a website where you can check this for any given url: http://saqoo.sh/a/labs/fblinkstats/

Comment: @alphapecap the URL you provided does not work - and it doesn't help as he asks for a api according to his tags.

Answer (score 15):

But ofcourse you can sir:

### Page likes

If it's a page you're wanting the amount of likes of, try such a thing as this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[Page name or ID here without the brackets]?fields=likes
```

Example:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/Facebook?fields=likes
```

Result:

```
{
    "likes": 90064323,
    "id": "20531316728"
}
```

---

### Specific URL likes

If it's a specific URL you want to get the likes of, try Facebook's FQL.
You can query the Facebook databases this way and get some info on URL's, here's an Example:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select like_count from link_stat where url='https://www.facebook.com/'&format=json
```

Result:

```
[{"like_count":1433567}]
```

The format in which this is returned can either be XML or JSON, where XML is the default. You can chance the format by adding the

```
&format=json
```

at the end.

There are multiple fields and tables that can be queried from, you can see all that good stuff in the sources.

Hope this helped some people, cause I was searching quite abit for it.

Have a nice day.

Sources:
Graph API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
FQL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get the likes in this format 10000 = 10K ?

Comment: @StevenBarragán: Facebook API will not return the data in that format, you can convert that yourself

Comment: Update: **fields=likes** does not apply for API 2.6, it has been changed to **fields=fan_count**

Answer (score 3):

You can always try by searching the social graph.
For example, the Apple's Facebook page has about 162K likes
https://graph.facebook.com/108521342513509

But if you try to get the "likes" number directly, you don't get anything.
http://graph.facebook.com/108521342513509/likes

Here is the link to the documentation. You might try use the "search" URL.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: I need the number of likes for any web pages outside Facebook, not just Facebook pages. The "search" API call didn't return any results when I searched for URLs.

Comment: An old post, but most people use "likes" for their facebook pages, even if the like box is on a specific webpage.