# Total number of Facebook Likes for entire domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there a way that I can retrieve the total number of Likes for my entire website for the day?
Essentially, I'd like to display the total number of Like for each blog post that day.

Comment: An real-world example of how to use some of this data would be greatly appreciated. The documentation has been running in circles... Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It's all time stats and not for the day but this simple Graph API call shows how many times an URL has been shared, for example:
https://graph.facebook.com/http://google.com

If you launch it everyday with every URL of your website, you can store the values and get daily stats.

Comment: This does not give any Like count

Comment: Jesus, downvoting a 5 years old answer, seriously? When that question was asked (and answered by me), the "like" button was gone in favour of the share one, so the only relevant data you could get is the number of shares. Now that the like button is back again, there are probably other methods available, like these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510044/can-i-get-the-number-of-facebook-likes-a-page-that-is-not-on-my-domain-received

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Facebook Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) to have statistics for your domain.

Cheers,

Comment: I've assigned my domain, but I'm still lost in figuring out how to grab the data I want and show it on my website. An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In FB Insights there's a graph called "Sharing" which seems like the "like" count would be but there's no "likes" key (closest is "links posted). Where is the total like count statistic?

Comment: For last one year or so, you can not even add a new domain. Is there any help? 

It says on platform insight page "You do not have any domains using insights." - but there is no instructions on how to add one. People are saying this functionality is broken for long time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some code into your website, as said in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0?locale=en_EN) so you can't do it for the domain you want, just for domains under your administration.

For the rest, just can get the likes for a single URL, using, for example, this [link](http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://google.com)

Comment: there is NO like counts

Answer (score -1):

[Total Likes](http://www.totallikes.com) shows only likes for current page, not whole websites, as it says. Try it with different urls.