# Graph API how get facebook page members/likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

[image]
[Facebook like check](http://www.sterntv-experimente.de/FacebookLikeCheck/#)

I've found an interesting app . 
This fb-app get all likes from any fanpage and sort it by mass and country!

> **My question:**

## how do these app get the data from the graph api ?

**First:**
get the fanpage-object no access token needed

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/

```
{
   "about": "The Coca-Cola Facebook Page is a collection of your stories showing how people from around the world have helped make Coke into what it is today.",
   "checkins": 146,
   "description": "Created in 1886 in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was first offered as a fountain beverage at Jacob's Pharmacy by mixing Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water. \n\nCoca-Cola was patented in 1887, registered as a trademark in 1893 and by 1895 it was being sold in every state and territory in the United States. In 1899, The Coca-Cola Company began franchised bottling operations in the United States. \n\nCoca-Cola might owe its origins to the United States, but its popularity has made it truly universal. Today, you can find Coca-Cola in virtually every part of the world.\n\nCoca-Cola Page House Rules: http://CokeURL.com/q28a",
   "founded": "1886",
   "is_published": true,
   "location": {
      "street": "",
      "zip": "",
      "latitude": 48.886763644968,
      "longitude": 2.2428464993582
      },
  "talking_about_count": 903212,
  "username": "coca-cola",
  "website": "http://www.coca-cola.com",
  "were_here_count": 0,
  "category": "Food/beverages",
  "id": "40796308305",
  "name": "Coca-Cola",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
  "likes": 58345623, 
  "cover": {
     "cover_id": "10152037156953306",
     "source": "http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/602289_10152037156953306_1443207674_n.jpg",
     "offset_y": 0
  }
}
```

**second**: get the likes from the facebook object:

[https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/likes?access_token=xxxxxxx](https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/likes?access_token=xxxx)

now i will receive all fan-page which "cocacola" like,
but i need  all users which like cocacola!

Maby its only possible with FQL Query ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With FB 2.6 API you can get total likes with `fan_count` field.

http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/?fields=fan_count&access_token={value}

Comment: Appears to also work with v3.2  https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/[page_id]/?fields=fan_count&access_token=XXXX

Comment: Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature.

what kind of access token do i need here?

Answer (score 23):

Facebook will not give you a list of users who like a page. You don't need this to create this app. You can get this data by querying publicly available [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) data.

This URL will get you the raw data this app uses to create this graph:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/insights/page_fans_country?access_token=XXXXXX
```

You can get this information with any valid `access_token`.

Comment: I tried this solution and even with a valid access_token I get an empty data object.

Comment: I just tried this in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=cocacola%2Finsights%2Fpage_fans_country) and it still works for me.

Comment: This works great, thanks. Do you know why other options from your linked page return an empty result? I've replaced `page_fans_country` with `page_fans_city` or `page_fans_gender_age` and just gettig back empty pages with paging

Comment: @Dev-otchka you have to request for the Extended Permission called read_insights. You will now get the number of likes for a page for each country.

Answer (score 1):

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/?fields=fan_count&access_token=#######

> You can get the facebook page member likes using the field fan_count. But you have to pass page access token rather than the user access_token.