# Can I get the number of likes from a facebook page without being the admin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My question is that. I'm trying to get the likes of a facebook page with facebook apigraph explorer but I can't get the count. I have look for other answers but they don't work to me so I'm thinking that it is because I'm not administrator, could be ?

I think that it is a simple thing so it have to be possible, as I can see the likes of a page entering in it on facebook.

I know that with ***/namepage/likes*** I can get all the likes but I need the count of all of them. For example:

***humorcabron/likes?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true)***

but I don't get the count of all of them.

Plese could you tell me How can i get the number of likes and what I'm getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graph API how get facebook page members/likes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632000/graph-api-how-get-facebook-page-members-likes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the previous versions of the api (before 2.5) works like I said at first
humorcabron?fields=likes.summary(true). At newer versions what I was looking for is **humorcabron?fields=fan_count**