# How to retrieve the number of fans for a page with Rfacebook in R?

Tags: r, facebook

I'm able to retrieve the number of comments, shares and likes for a post of a Facebook page but I can't find a way to retrieve the number of likes (or "fans") a page has.

It is stated in the documentation that "To retrieve the number of likes for a page, use getUsers with the page IDs.".

My problem is that the `getUsers()` function return an error and `getPage()` contains no information regarding the number of fans, but only the number of likes per every single post.

```
> install.packages("Rfacebook")
> library(Rfacebook)
> token <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
> getUsers("179106818789009", token=token)
Error in callAPI(query, token) : 
  (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (first_name) on node type (Page)
>
```

How can I find this information ?

A workaround that uses the Facebook API with an url as proposed in another question also return an error :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/?fields=fan_count&access_token=MY_TOKEN_HERE

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#12) fan_count field requires version v2.6 or higher",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 12,
      "fbtrace_id": "F8JOCmpvFnX"
   }
}
```

[Graph API how get facebook page members/likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632000/graph-api-how-get-facebook-page-members-likes)

Comment: so...why not use a higher api version then, as the error message suggests?

Comment: After my token expired I finally get it works with an OAuth Facebook app authentification, with : `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/?fields=fan_count&access_token=app_id|app_secret
`

Comment: Not sure what was wrong with the temporary token because the app is v2.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments section I managed to get the `fan_count` by requesting the API with this url : `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/?fields=fan_count&access‌​_token=app_id|app_se‌​cret`

It needed a Facebook App that provides permanent access to the Facebook API.