# get count of facebook likes with SDK api()

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know there is a way to get the number of facebook likes using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623434/2545680):

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27https://stackoverflow.com/%27&format=json

But I can't figure out how I can do the same using facebook JavaScript SDK `api()`. Does anybody know if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured that out myself:

```
FB.api(
    "/" + siteUrl,
    function (response) {}
);
```

Comment: Accept this as an answer.

Comment: been site url the facebook page or the actual domain?